# yarn errors when attempting to install node-opus?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to install `node-opus` through `yarn add node-opus` on Windows Subsystem for Linux (I'm not sure if this is even possible but I'm trying) and I'm running into errors in the process:

it's looking like the main error is: `gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make` but I feel like this is a misleading error as I've installed other packages before this one just fine?

````
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.11.1 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/ref/build/config.gypi', 
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/ref',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/bin/node\" \"/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/ref
gyp ERR! node -v v12.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok"
[2/2] ⠂ node-opus
error /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/node-opus: Command failed. 
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/node-opus
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@12.11.1 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at "/usr/bin/python"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/node-opus/build/config.gypi', 
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/tai/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/node-opus',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make 
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tai/dev/FutabaBot/node_modules/node-opus
gyp ERR! node -v v12.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was that I lacked `build-essential` - installing that (via `sudo apt-get install build-essential`) solved the issue for me and got things moving again.